# Assigning a JSON response from a sql query to variables in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to query a mysql database in my rails app that contains my archive of guitar tabs.  I am just trying to query the database, assign the id, artist, song, and url of each tab to a variable in my TabsController to display in my tab.html.erb view.  Here is the code I have:

```
    class TabsController < ApplicationController

        def show
           @tabs = Tab.find_by_sql("Select * from gp where artist='led zeppelin'")


           respond_to do |format|
             format.html # show.html.erb
             format.json { render json: @tabs} #  

           end  
        end

     end
```

My query is successful and in my view it displays the json reponse of all the tabs.  My challenge is to assign the guitar tabs id, artist, song, and url to different variables.  I have a feeling the solution is going to be simple, but I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling the browser that response format is going to be a json, so you won't be able to format that differently. If you're just trying to display all of the tabs, why don't you make your action a lot simpler:

```
def show
  @tabs = Tab.find_by_sql("Select * from gp where artist='led zeppelin'")
end
```

And then in `show.html.erb` it would look something like (what I'm assuming your data structure is)

```
<% @tabs.each do |tab| %>
  ID: <%= tab.id %>
  Artist: <%= tab.artist %>
  Song: <%= tab.song %>
  URL: <%= tab.url %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TabsController < ApplicationController
    def show
       @tabs = Tab.find_by_sql("Select * from gp where artist='led zeppelin'")


       respond_to do |format|
         format.html # show.html.erb
         format.json { render json: @tabs.map{|t| {:id => t.id, :artist => t.artist, ...}}} 
       end  
    end
 end
```